# How to get use index to get a value from unicode data type in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

Sorry for asking a repeating question, but I am stuck here. In my code, a variable contains the following data:

```
{  
"AlarmName":"ZDR ALARAM - 404 - ERROR",
"AlarmDescription":"This will check the 404 Errors in ZDR server",
"Trigger":{  
   "MetricName":"ZDR4dor",
   "Namespace":"ZDRLdics",
   "StatisticType":"Statistic",
   "Statistic":"SUM",
   "Unit":null,
   "Dimensions":[       ],
   "Period":60,
   "EvaluationPeriods":1,
   "ComparisonOperator":"GreatergrfdgsThreshold",
   "Threshold":0,
   "TreatMissingData":"",
   "EvaluatxcbleCountPercentile":""
}
}
```

I need to get `AlarmName`. I am using `var['AlarmName']`, but it shows the error **index must be an integer not string**. When I use `var[0]` it shows the output
**{** 
only,

The object type is `<type 'unicode'>`

How do I get the exact value of the key **'AlarmName'**?

Comment: Your variable seems to be the string containing this content. You want it to be a dictionary object. Try `import json; json.loads(x)['AlarmName']`.

Comment: when i use `type(variable_name)` it show the data type is `type<'unicode'>`

Comment: That is what I said, it is a (unicode) string. You need to parse it into a dictionary format. Since it is a legal `json` object, using the `json` module and its parser is probably the easiest way.

Comment: its working.......! Thanks a lot
:)  @Graipher

Comment: Nice! I wrote that up as an answer, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your `var` is just a (unicode) string containing the information. You need to parse it, so it is a dictionary object, which can handle the item access. The easiest way is to use the `json` module, since your string seems to be a valid `json` object:

```
import json

var = """
{  
"AlarmName":"ZDR ALARAM - 404 - ERROR",
"AlarmDescription":"This will check the 404 Errors in ZDR server",
"Trigger":{  
   "MetricName":"ZDR4dor",
   "Namespace":"ZDRLdics",
   "StatisticType":"Statistic",
   "Statistic":"SUM",
   "Unit":null,
   "Dimensions":[       ],
   "Period":60,
   "EvaluationPeriods":1,
   "ComparisonOperator":"GreatergrfdgsThreshold",
   "Threshold":0,
   "TreatMissingData":"",
   "EvaluatxcbleCountPercentile":""
}
}
"""

var = json.loads(var)
print(var['AlarmName'])
# ZDR ALARAM - 404 - ERROR
```